# Spring Boot Actuator error 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using spring boot 2.0.3.RELEASE when I deploy my application apparently are exposed the endpoints of the actuator but when I try to access any of them, I get a error 406 Not Acceptable.

```
2018-09-06 09:38:52.982  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 15 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2018-09-06 09:38:52.990  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/auditevents],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-06 09:38:52.991  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/beans],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-06 09:38:52.991  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-06 09:38:52.991  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/conditions],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-06 09:38:52.991  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/configprops],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-06 09:38:52.991  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/env],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-06 09:38:52.992  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/env/{toMatch}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-06 09:38:52.992  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-06 09:38:52.992  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/loggers],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-06 09:38:52.992  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/loggers/{name}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-06 09:38:52.992  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/loggers/{name}],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-06 09:38:52.992  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/heapdump],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-06 09:38:52.993  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/threaddump],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-06 09:38:52.993  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/metrics/{requiredMetricName}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-06 09:38:52.993  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/metrics],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-06 09:38:52.993  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/scheduledtasks],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-06 09:38:52.993  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/httptrace],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-06 09:38:52.993  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/mappings],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-09-06 09:38:52.994  INFO 3416 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto protected java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.Link>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.links(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
```

[Error 406](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKCSt.png)

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: Please provide pom.xml and your endpoint definition.

Answer (score 0):

Add @EnableWebMvc or @EnableWebFlux to an @Configuration class.

Example for web-flux and actuator:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class MyConfiguration implements WebFluxConfigurer {
}
```